# traits if a type `T` has a `template<> struct Writer<T>` to serialize itself

Tags: c++, templates

I have a Writer struct to do some serialization

```
template<typename T>
struct Writer {};  // only specialized version has ::wrap_t

template<>
struct Writer <int> {
    typedef int wrap_t;
};
template <typename T>
using Writer_wrap_t = typename Writer<T>::wrap_t;

template<>
struct Writer<float> {
    typedef float wrap_t;
};
```

And I want to know whether a type has a specialized Writer. The code does not work as expect:

```
template<typename T, typename U = Writer_wrap_t <T>>
struct has_writer : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_writer<T, void> : std::false_type {};

int main() {
    bool b = has_writer <double>::value;
    // error C2794: 'wrap_t': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'Writer<T>'
    // error C2976: 'has_reflect': too few template arguments
    // error C2938: 'Writer_wrap_t ' : Failed to specialize alias template
}
```

I suppose that `has_writer<double>` didn't use the specialized version `struct has_writer<T, void> : std::false_type {};`?

But now there is a substitution failure for the first one, shouldn't the compiler try to instantiate the second version?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using (this is really easy to do with C++20, but still doable with C++17/11)

Comment: I am actually using c++17 now, because the code needs to compile with clang8 & android ndk r20. But if necessary I can upgrade the toolchain.

Comment: Can we assume only the specialized types have `wrap_t`?

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 yes, that's true.

Comment: If you are using C++17 then there is a IMO cleaner way of achieving what you want. C++17 added a lot of template programming features. I know this is not really an answer to this question, but maybe there is something in it for you. Example code here : https://godbolt.org/z/EY1rhxbz5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using SFINAE correctly. The typical pattern is to define a primary template where the second template parameter is `void`

```
template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_writer : std::false_type {};
```

and then specialize the template using `std::void_t` of whatever type you want to check as the second parameter

```
template<typename T>
struct has_writer<T, std::void_t<Writer_wrap_t <T>>> : std::true_type {};
```

If the type you pass to `void_t` is well-formed, the specialization is chosen, which is the true case, otherwise the primary is chosen, which is the false case. `Writer_wrap_t` itself is only well-formed if the type passed to it has a member typedef `wrap_t`.

Comment: make sense too. But is it just a typical pattern to do so or there is a reason why am I not using SFINAE correctly?

Comment: @Joey.Z This is the idiomatic way to solve the problem, though there are other ways to formulate this. Your attempt fails because you're trying to have sfinae happen in the default template parameter, which doesn't work. As the error message says, it tries to instantiate that parameter, and produces a hard error when it fails.

Comment: Intuitively, `template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value> >` this is very common to select a overloaded version of function template base on the SFINAE happens in a default template parameter.

Comment: @Joey.Z That is not the idiomatic way for a function template either. `template<class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_array<T>::value, int> = 0>` is the better way to write it. Using the default value will break with multiple overloads or if the parameter is explicitly specified.

Comment: @super Tried with visualc++, you are right. Just the usage is demoed in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if#Example here with #5 item.